# Seeking recommendations for low code or no code IDE for building a web based application like TripAdvisor

Tags: ide, rad

There are many to choose from, most are too expensive to consider for building a prototype in pre-funding, pre-start-up organization so needs to be low cost.

I would like this to be something that can deploy applications accessed via a web browser and as an app, sharing the same back-end database, and deploy live to a few 100 users/customers.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can give a try to [zoho creator](https://www.zoho.com/creator/) a low code platform. It is cheap is market

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into the functionality and licencing and share what I find.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm sure this will provide what I need, I am not sure how the licensing would work out when delivering the app to the public, as Zoho is intended for use within an organisation.  I've settled on www.bubble.io as a no/low code development environment.

Answer (score 0):

Oracle APEX.  It’s free and comes with their database.  Oracle’s XE version of their database is also free.

[Oracle APEX download](https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/apex-v191-downloads.html)

[Oracle XE Database - comes with APEX installed](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/xe-downloads.html)

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. The solution looks good but is a bit more technical than I want at this time.  After a lot of research I've settled on www.bubble.io

Comment: @RayW no problem.  Best of luck with your choice.

Answer (score 0):

[Kintone](https://www.kintone.com/) is a no-code/low-code platform that fits your needs.

Kintone's [developer site](https://developer.kintone.io/) provides a free Kintone environment for developers (the Developer License) to prototype and test out Kintone's features and APIs. You can find the guide to get the free environment [here](https://developer.kintone.io/hc/en-us/articles/220582587).